# Move vuetify styles to css file when server side rendering

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I've been using vuetify as frontend, but since I moved to nuxt. All styles are displayed within html page.

Is there a way to move vuetify styles to separate css files?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [extractCSS](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#extractcss) property from nuxt.config

```
export default {
  build :{
    extractCSS: true
  }
}
```

Comment: @Learner surely. It will work, in case you copy pasted i spelled it wrong. CSS should be uppercased, updated

Comment: @Learner yes, it is. What version of nuxt?  And how do u tell its not working?

Comment: @Learner fyi there will be some critical css still left on the page

Comment: Sorry I needed to go.. Well when I check page source I have so much to scroll down where I see almost every css class for buttons etc.

Comment: Seems like it works when you create new nuxt/vuetify app. But when you create nuxt and add vuetify after it doesnt. For me at least. By making new app it added a lot of config for vuetify.